# libproject not found in Google Play Services 31

Tags: android, google-play-services

I need to find libproject folder to import Google Play Services to Eclipse, to import google play services on a project.

I install Google Play services 31 in "Android SDK Manager". When access to downloaded path I find:

[image]

I last version I have libproject:

[image]

¿Where is libproject to import google play services 31 in my Eclipse project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play services no longer ships a `libproject` directory and does not officially support development in Eclipse.

You'll have to use an older version or find an unofficial workaround if you want to use (the now completely deprecated) Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue because I'm still using Eclipse. I was able to integrate Play Services revision 31 in my project using the following steps:

1. Start Android SDK Manager and choose to install Extras > Google Repository.
2. Navigate to android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-games\VERSION\
3. Change the extension of the .AAR file to .ZIP and extract the contents into a temporary location.
4. Go to the extracted folder and create a new directory called "lib", and move the "classes.jar" file into it.
5. Import the folder into Eclipse as existing Android code. Once imported you may need to set the project as Library and set the appropriate compile API level.
6. Now go back to the android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-games\VERSION\ folder and open up the pom file using any text editor and look at the dependancies section to see which other libraries it depends on.
7. Repeat the steps again for the new libraries you've identified as dependancies in the earlier step.

You have to keep checking all the dependancies until you've identified all the libraries you need for your project's purposes. For example, my project uses Ads, Cloud Save and Leaderboards/Achievements, so I did this process and ended up with 9 libraries to import into Eclipse (see attached screenshot).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8IUU.png)